# VS2012 incorrectly renames codebehind when renaming markup file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, vs-web-site-project, web-essentials

In Visual Studio 2012, when I rename an aspx file, VS automatically renames the codebehind file but drops the `.aspx` from the file name. Because it is still nested as a codebehind, I cannot rename it.  The current workaround is to close VS and reopen it, at which point the file - since it ends in `.cs` rather than `.aspx.cs` - is no longer recognized as a codebehind file.

*File is created (or copied from another):*
[image: Example 1]

*.aspx is lost when renaming to `Default1.aspx`:*
[image: Example 2]

*close and reopen Visual Stuio to find this:*
[image: Example 3]

*rename to add the missing `.aspx`:*
[image: Example 4]

*finally have a correctly named codebehind:*
[image: Example 5]

This has been happening to a colleague for a while and only recently started happening to me (no catalyst I can think of).  Anyone know how to correct the auto-naming of the codebehind file?

Note: This problem only occurs on a website. Renaming functions as expected in a WebApp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same problem. The problem goes away when I disable Web Essentials 2012 (not really a solution - but it seems to be the cause).

Comment: Thanks.  That's just what I was looking for. I've verified that that is indeed causing the bug. Now to let them know about it.

Comment: Okay so here is a dumb question. How do I disable Web Essentials? Didn't even know it was installed.